# How to resolve missing dependency for installed CocoaPod?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, dependencies, cocoapods

I added the UNIRest cocoapod and installation was successful. Building my project fails because UNIRest classes in Pod project can't reference foundation classes like NSObject. I tried "pod try UNIRest" and I can successfully build UNIRest only.

I was able to fix the build failure by explicitly including CoreData.framework to Pod project. Foundation.framework was already there but highlighted in red. Not sure what that means either.

Have I just gotten around something but not really fixed the real issue?
If foundation.framework was already there, why is it not finding NSObject?

Answer (score 0):

Try "pod setup" after installing, I had a similar issue and solved it using this. You may also need to install it again after the command.

Comment: Wanted to make sure I understood. Should I run 'pod setup' again after 'pod install'? I followed the instructions on http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2. I ran pod setup prior to creating/editing the pod file.

Comment: Yes, thats what i ment

Comment: Taking a closer look at this today and the reference to Foundation.framework in the /Pod project is pointing to a version of SDK that doesn't exist. The podFile points to    platform :ios, '8.1' but is looking for iPhoneOS7.1.sdk which I don't have at all!

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed with Mashape that an import for Foundation/Foundation.h was missing in Unirest.h. They have published an update.